# Extract a string after some string

Tags: python

I have a text paragraph `my_text` which contains lines like

```
........ licensed in Bangladesh. We are happy to announce ......................
................................................
```

I want to extract the word "Bangladesh" from it. To decide if i want that word depends upon the presence of "licensed in" in the sentence.

Current code is like:

```
texts = my_text.split("licensed in")
# extract the word before the first dot (.) from texts[1]
```

What is more appropriate way to do it in python?

Comment: is it always in the format `licensed in Bangladesh` or can there be other words before the substring you want to get?

Comment: It is always in 'licensed in ....' format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a job for a regex:

```
import re
location = re.search(r"licensed in ([^.]*)", my_text).group(1)
```

**Explanation:**

```
licensed\ in\   # Match "licensed in "
(               # Match and capture in group 1:
 [^.]*          # Any number of characters except dots.
)               # End of capturing group 1
```

Comment: I don't understand why would some one down vote this answer? The answer has an explanation and it is clear as well as it is exactly what OP requested! Down voters are requested to comment if possible for the reasons, it helps the user to improve his/her answer further.

Comment: Is the dot '.' always present after the searched word? Maybe a better solution to extract "Bangladesh" even if the following char is not a dot is to use boudary word: `re.search(r"licensed in (\b\w+\b)", txt).group(1)`

Comment: @Antwane: The first word boundary wouldn't be necessary, and the regex would match incorrectly on inputs like `"Sri Lanka"` (while mine would match incorrectly on `"U.S.A."` - it extracts anything before the first dot, as asked. Strictly speaking, the dot isn't required; if there is no dot, the match will extend until the end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> my_text.split('licensed in ')[1].split('.')[0]
'Bangladesh'
```

Comment: Isn't this the same solution that the OP said they already tried?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is. But I just think that the OP will not want to mess with regex, so split() is the best choice here.